# More that one Puppet agent stopped connecting to the Master

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

Puppet Master version 3.7.1
Puppet Agent version 0.25.4

Hi there Guys,
I'm still in the beginning stages of using puppet running at lease 10 agents.
I have written 20 odd modules and all worked fine.

Yesterday I tried adding custom facts and got this error:

```
Failed to retrieve current state of resource: Could not retrieve information from source
```

I thought it may be certificate related so I revoked the agent's cert with a normal

```
puppet cert clean agentname
```

I also removed the /var/lib/puppet/ssl directory.

When I now do

```
puppetd --test **or** puppet agent --test
```

I now always get this

```
err: Could not retrievw catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I know this is some certificate mixup BUT,
I have already tried to

```
1. Removed the master /var/lib/puppet/ssl
2. Restarted the master
3. Removed the agent /var/lib/puppet/ssl
4. Ran puppet agent --test
```

Comment: What is the output of: `puppet cert --list --all`?

Comment: And maybe you should first go through this: [Troubleshooting Connections Between Components](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/trouble_comms.html)

Comment: why `Puppet Agent version 0.25.4` instead of `3.7.1`?

Comment: for the client "puppet cert clean agentname" from your master and in your client /var/lib/puppet/ssl and use updated puppet client

Comment: `puppet:/etc/puppet # puppet cert --list --all`
`+ "agent.fqdn.co.za" (SHA256)` 
`+ "puppet.fqdn.co.za"        (SHA256)`

Comment: Connection to the puppet master is fine as it signs the certificates. `agent.fqdn.co.za # telnet puppet 8140`
`Trying 10.10.1.215...`
`Connected to puppet.`
`Escape character is '^]'.`

Answer (score 0):

As the ssl directory has been removed from the master, the puppetmaster needs to be restarted.

Once restarted a new ssl directory has been created. When an agent run has been completed a certificate sign request should be visible on the master.

Comment: The Master does receive the request and signs the certificate. I can even see it under --list --all but I still get the same error from the agent's side.

Answer (score 0):

1. I removed the `autosign.conf` from the `/etc/puppet directory`
2. I removed the `autosign=true` from the `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`
3. `puppet cert clean <NODE NAME>`                 (On the Master)
4. `rm -r $(puppet agent --configprint ssldir)`    (On the Agent)
5. `puppet agent --test`                           (On the Agent)
6. `puppet cert sign <NODE NAME>`                  (On the Master)

And it worked... For some Bizarre reason